# Get string representation of id in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, nsstring

How do you get the best string representation of an `id` object?

Is the following correct? Is there a simpler way?

```
id value;
NSString* valueString = nil;
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    valueString = value;
} else if ([value respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
    valueString = [value stringValue];
} else if ([value respondsToSelector:@selector(description)]) {
    valueString = [value description];
}
```

Comment: Interesting concept. How'd you run into this issue?

Comment: NSObject has description property which returns a name of class string . The derived object can implement description of NSObject Protocol to return anything more meanigful.

Comment: @esqew I have to log an id and I want the log message to be as helpful as possible.

Comment: So for your classes you can override "description" to return more meaningful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `description` method is part of the [`NSObject` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html), so any object in Cocoa will respond to it; you can thus just send `description`:

```
for( id obj in heterogeneousCollection ){
    [obj description];
}
```

Also, `NSLog()` will send `description` to any object passed as an argument to the `%@` specifier.

Note that you should not use this method for purposes other than logging/debugging. That is, you should not rely on the description of a framework class having a particular format between versions of the framework and start doing things like constructing objects based on another's description string.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that `description` returns nice formatted values if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Since all objects inherit from NSObject, they all respond to the description method. Simply override this method in your classes to get your desired result.

The description method in some Cocoa classes like NSNumber call the stringValue method internally. For instance...

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2f];
NSString *description1 = num.stringValue;
NSString *description2 = [num description];

NSLog("%@", description1);
NSLog("%@", description2);
```

...have the same output:

```
Printing description of description1:
0.2
Printing description of description2:
0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I like mine to look nice: sometimes Xcode strips the newline other times not, so YMMV:

```
- (NSString *)description   // also used for comparison purposes
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];
#ifndef NDEBUG // so in Distribution build, this does not get included
    [str appendFormat:@"Address ID=\"%@\"\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kID]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  usrID:      %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADuserID]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  first:      %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADfirstName]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  last:       %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADlastName]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  address:    %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADaddress]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  suite:      %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADsuiteApt]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  city:       %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADcity]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  state:      %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADstate]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  zip:        %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADzipCode]];
    [str appendFormat:@"  phone:      %@\n", [self.privateDict objectForKey:kADphone]];
#endif
    return str;
}
```